# On-premises data gateway location for PowerBI

Tags: azure, powerbi

How can I check where I have installed On-premises data gateway for one PowerBI report?

I looking for solution to find in which server I have installed gateway used by my report. I need it because it gives me error: DM_GWPipeline_Client_GatewayUnreachable.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like the gateway went offline so the service cannot know more info about the Gateway. 
Do you have your Recovery Key? It's the key you have provided on install time. If you do, you can install the gateway on a new machine, when you sign in you will be asked whether you want to create a new gateway or restore an existing one, choose "Restore" and that will migrate the existing gateway to the new machine and move all settings and reports that had been associated to the old gateway.

Comment: What if I don't have recovery key?

Comment: Hmm first thing, you should keep the Recovery key for similar situations, as you can't recover the recovery key today. 
Unfortunately there's no way to figure the gateway location or recover it in your case, so you'll have to setup a new gateway.

Answer (score 0):

Usually, the default path is:
C:\Program Files\On-premises data gateway

You can also check in services

1. Open Services from Windows
2. Check for service "On-premises data gateway service"
3. Click on Logon Tab
4. This will show you the account you used for this service